# Add offset on iScroll to allow the last item to be on top

Tags: javascript, iscroll4

I am trying to make a list of `<li>`'s so that when I click on one, it goes up to the top of the page, no matter if it is the last one or if there's just two on the list. I call scrollToElement() but it bounces back because of the lack of padding after the element. I have tried appending a `<li>` element of height 2000px, but the list will bounce back, making the last element go back to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I needed to call .refresh() after appending the padding `<li>`. Afterwards, it will scroll past the bottom like expected.